# How access the data that are going to be Saved in the "insertMany" middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm triyng to hash the password of a list of users that i load with a seeder.
I can access the docs keys and values but i'm not able to modify them before saving.

This is the code that i'm using.

```
UserSchema.pre("insertMany", async function (next, docs) {
  try {
    docs.map(async function (doc) {
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
      doc.password = await bcrypt.hash(doc.password, salt);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for-loop` instead of `.map`.

In mongoose 5.x, instead of calling next() manually, you can use a function that returns a promise. In particular, you can use async/await.

```
UserSchema.pre("insertMany", async function (docs) {
  try {
    for (const doc of docs) {
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
      doc.password = await bcrypt.hash(doc.password, salt);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your changes are not saved is because your promises are never resolved.

The result of your map is a list of promises and you should await it too.
To do that you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) : `await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)`.

In your case, the code will be:

```js
UserSchema.pre("insertMany", async function (next, docs) {
  try {
    await Promise.all(docs.map(async function (doc) {
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
      doc.password = await bcrypt.hash(doc.password, salt);
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  next();
});
```